# Using swap buffers with boost conditional_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, buffer

I'm trying to write video recorder using front and back buffer and two threads, this code works but its really hard to debug multithreaded code, so I'm not sure if this code will work 100% of times, I'd really appreciate if someone can look this and check if I am not missing anything.

Basic idea is, 
encode thread is waiting for frontbuffer
in this time record thread is filling back buffer, when it finish, it switches buffers.
Encode thread is encoding front buffer and record buffer is filling backbuffer again.

```
boost::mutex frontbuflock_;
boost::condition_variable ready_cond_;
raw_buffer_t raw_buf[2];
raw_buffer_t* raw_back_buffer_ = 0;
raw_buffer_t* raw_front_buffer_ = 0;
boost::atomic_bool front_buffer_ready_;

void record_thread()
{
    do
    {
        int32_t* p = &raw_back_buffer_->at(0);

        [[[ fill backbuffer with image data here ]]]

        frontbuflock_.lock();

        //swap buffers
        raw_buffer_t* tmp = raw_front_buffer_;
        raw_front_buffer_ = raw_back_buffer_;
        raw_back_buffer_ = tmp;

        front_buffer_ready_ = 1;

        ready_cond_.notify_one();
        frontbuflock_.unlock();

    }while(!stop_);
}

void encode_thread()
{
    do
    {
        while(!front_buffer_ready_)
            ready_cond_.wait(lock);

        frontbuflock_.lock();

        [[[ encode frontbuffer here ]]]

        front_buffer_ready_ = 0;
        frontbuflock_.unlock();
    }while(!stop_);
}
```

ive found a little thing, lets say record thread notifies condition variable and releases frontbuflock, encode thread should lock frontbuffer but theres small possibility that record thread will fill backbuffer and lock frontbuffer again before encode thread will lock it. in this case ill lose one frame, im not sure if i should even bother prevent this.

Comment: At a quick glance, you seem to be using more locking than you'd have to.

Comment: You do too much locking. Also, for simple data like boolean flag, that is used by multiple threads, use atomics instead of locks. Compare-exchange (used in the right way) can nicely improve speed of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a few unit tests for it using your favourite testing framework, and then run the tests in helgrind. It's a tool for detecting synchronisation errors which is part of valgrind: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html.

From my personal experience with valgrind tools, I'd set the sensitivity to minimum initially, because these tools usually report a lot of errors. Some of them are not your fault, but the libraries you're using. You want to get the low hanging fruit first. Once you fixed or suppressed the major errors, move to the less serious ones. Rinse & repeat.

Happy debugging! :)